# Javaparser: Visit all node types with one method

Tags: java, parsing, javaparser

I am using [Javaparser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) to parse Java source code.

Is there a way to implement a Visitor that can visit the abstract Node class?

I want to visit every Node and print its line number, but I don't want to implement a visit() method for every Node type (AssignExpr, BinaryExpr, IfStmt, etc...) because there are so many types.

Comment: That link is a deprecated link as said in the page .Refer [Github for latest code](http://javaparser.github.io/javaparser/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A visitor makes sense only to process different types of element. You can instead start from the root (the CompilationUnit) and pass it to your method process:

`void process(Node node){
    // Do something with the node
    for (Node child : node.getChildrenNodes()){
        process(child);
    }
}`

Disclaimer: I am a JavaParser contributor